# What the different iOS Apple Push Notification (Sandbox) / (Sandbox & Production)

Tags: ios, push-notification

On developer.apple.com -> Create a New Certificate
It has UI updated, a new option "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)", is it mean i can use one .pem and same token cross sandbox & production send and receive ios remote notification?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ7bi.png)

Comment: Note that key/token-based push notifications are better these days. They don't expire like certificates and you can use one for all of your apps. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this single SSL certificate, you can send APN push notifications from your server to iOS devices (both development and production)

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_certificate-based_connection_to_apns